# Are there any proofs that BQP is not in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing

**Are there any proofs that BQP is not in P?**  In laymen's terms, I am asking if there is any formal proof separating the complexity class that quantum computers are presently assumed to solve efficiently from the complexity class that non-quantum computers are presently known to solve efficiently.

Obviously I'm not talking here about black box/oracle proofs that show they are nonequivalent *if we have access to some theoretical oracle*.  Just talking about regular, normal equivalence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a famous open problem, so you won't find a proof anywhere at this time. We don't even know how to prove that $\mathsf{P\neq PSPACE}$, so finer separation of complexity classes such as $\mathsf{P\neq BQP}$ is also not known. Note that $\mathsf{BQP\subseteq PSPACE}$ is not trivial, you can find a proof in [Quantum complexity theory](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~dipierro/InfQuant/articles/BV.pdf), by Bernstein & Vazirani.

It is suspected that they are different, with the ability of quantum computers to factor integers in polynomial time being a strong witness.